# Ubuntu 9.04, Postfix, Dovecot, Squirrelmail, and vacation/away messages

Tags: postfix, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, dovecot, webmail

I'm attempting to set up a mailserver for a small office. FYI, we're replacing Kerio Mailserver on OS X with Postfix, Dovecot, postfixadmin, and Squirrelmail on Ubuntu Jaunty (9.04.)

I installed the "dovecot-postfix" package, and configured them, and my test server is now accepting and sending messages via SMTP, and I can connect with POP/IMAP clients and receive email. I can log into postfixadmin over the web and add users. I followed this (excellent) walkthrough: [http://craigballinger.com/blog/2009/07/postfix-dovecot-mailserver-on-ubuntu-904-jaunty-jackalope/](https://web.archive.org/web/20091120063458/https://craigballinger.com/blog/2009/08/postfix-vacation-autoresponder/)

The main feature I'm lacking now is the ability for users to set vacation/away messages. The squirrelmail plugins don't seem well-suited to the setup I have (where user info is stored in MySQL).

This: http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Sieve seems like my best bet, but I can't really fit my head around how all this stuff is supposed to work together to provide a web interface to set vacation/away messages. I'm looking for the best solution for getting vacation messages up and running with my current setup, or a suggestion for an alternate setup. (So far this is just a test server, with production still running on Kerio, so starting over IS an option.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad the walkthrough was helpful. While not a perfect solution, (considering you're using Squirrelmail) I did just post a followup on implementing postfixadmin's virtual vacation plugin. [http://craigballinger.com/blog/2009/08/postfix-vacation-autoresponder/](https://web.archive.org/web/20091120063458/https://craigballinger.com/blog/2009/08/postfix-vacation-autoresponder/) It should at least give you an option if you haven't found a solution yet. I'm currently writing a plugin for roundcube's webmail app that will give users access to the autoresponder functionality from inside their webmail. Hopefully the first build of that isn't too far out.

Comment: Thanks, Craig! Although I don't have this completely working yet, it's been tremendously helpful. I'll keep my eyes open for your roundcube plugin too -- I'm certainly not married to Squirrelmail.

Comment: And when I redid both walkthroughs from scratch, I've got everything working! (All hail VMWare's "Revert To Snapshot" functionality for getting me back to a blank slate.)

Also, all hail Craig! Both excellent walkthroughs got me where I need to go. (And I'm not at all concerned that users need to go to postfixadmin to set their vacation stuff.)

Thanks again, Craig!

Answer (score 0):

I used a modified version of the "Virtual Vacation" script from Postfixadmin to do this.  Modifying the vacation manager squirrelmail plugin to use the DB instead of files was a piece of cake from there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a /var/vmail/globalsieverc file

```
require ["fileinto"];
# Move spam to spam folder
if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" ["YES"] {
  fileinto "spam";
  stop;
}
```

chown vmail /var/vmail/globalsieverc

in the plugin {} Section define:

```
sieve_global_path = /var/vmail/globalsieverc
```

In your /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf file add  managesieve to your protocols:

```
protocols = imap imaps pop3 pop3s managesieve
```

apt-get install avelsieve

know you can you use the "filters" link in squirrelmail

have fun

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at http://feurix.org/projects/response/ for a vacation autoresponder designed for virtual users (works fine with other lookup table types). It stores vacation config and -messages in MySQL or PostgreSQL. All SQL queries can be customized.